Service Account Role and Scope Relation while creating Virtual Machine
I have created a new Virtual Machine with custom defined service account. I have given "Storage Object Creator" & "Storage Object Viewer" roles to the service account. Now while creating the Virtual Machine, I have selected the Storage Cloud API access scope as Read/Write.
Now what I noticed is that even if I remove the "Storage Object Creator" role from the service account, I can still create objects under Cloud Storage Bucket by issuing the below command from inside VM.
gsutil cp new1.png gs://demo-suddeb-bucket/

So the confusion that I have now -

What is the best practice? Define Storage Cloud API access scope while creating VM or add roles in custom service account? Seems like when we define the Cloud API Access Scope, it simply ignores what role you have in your service account?
Is that correct or am I missing something?

